# js heap memory is always growing when replacing the value of a certain attribute of the state slice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, garbage-collection

I am using CRA and redux to create an MVP for checking the used JS heap memory. Even though I run the MVP in production by running `npm run build` and `serve -s build` commands. The used JS heap memory is not my expectation. See below code and details:

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useEffect } = React;
const { createStore } = Redux;
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;

function reducer(state = { data: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_DATA':
      return { ...state, data: new Array(1000000 * 100).join('a') };
    case 'CLEAR':
      return { ...state, data: [] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector((state) => state.data);

  console.log({ state });

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR' });
    };
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'SET_DATA' })}>set data</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR' })}>clear</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><Provider store={store}><App /></Provider></StrictMode>);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/redux@4.2.1/dist/redux.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@8.1.2/dist/react-redux.js"></script>
```

Every time I click the "set data" button, I can see the JS heap memory increase by 100MB. When I click the "clear" button, the JS heap memory does not decrease.

Used JS heap memory information:

[image]

I definitely updated the redux state correctly, I think the used JS heap memory should always be 100MB no matter how many times I click the "set data" button. But after I clicked the "set data" button three times, it increased to 300MB.

Why is this happening? Even though I click the "Collect garbage" button on Memory Tool. The used JS heap memory is still 300MB.

Microsoft Edge: 116.0.1938.69

Comment: I'm not familiar with Edge's dev tools so I did some investigation in Firefox: (1) Take a memory snapshot with "Record call stacks" enabled. (2) Inspect the snapshot, changing the view to "[Dominators](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/memory/dominators_view/index.html)".

Comment: (3) Find the relevant entry and view the "retaining paths". The retaining paths shows what's keeping the object in memory. Changing the "label by" to "call stack" shows the specific places in code where objects are being allocated/retained. With this information, I found this GitHub issue which may be relevant: [#1981: Bug: Stale selectors keep old store referenced and in memory](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1981)

Comment: I don't have time to investigate further so hopefully the above will be of some use even if it doesn't answer the question.